# How to pass entire props to a child component with TypeScript & Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, contentful

I want to pass entire objects of `contents` in `Interface Props` to `RichText.tsx`.

Below is what I tried;

```
interface Props {
    title: string;
    contents: {
        content: [
            {
                content: [
                    {
                        nodeType: string;
                        value: string;
                    }
                ];
                nodeType: string;
                data: { key: string };
            }
        ];
    };
}

const PostDetail: React.FC<Props> = ({ title, contents }) => {
    return (
        <PageLayout>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <RichText content={contents} />
        </PageLayout>
    );
};
```

The result is that `RichText` component received the object like this;

```
{
    content: [
        {
            nodeType: string;
            value: string;
        }
    ];
    nodeType: string;
    data: { key: string };
}
```

But I want the component to have the object in this style...

```
{
    content: [
        {
            content: [
                {
                    nodeType: string;
                    value: string;
                }
            ];
            nodeType: string;
            data: { key: string };
        }
    ];
}
```

I thought this was because I specified the key "content" when passing props, so I tried using spread operator to pass the props as shown below.

```
const PostDetail: React.FC<Props> = ({ title, contents }) => {
    return (
        <PageLayout>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <RichText {...contents} />
        </PageLayout>
    );
};
```

However, I got an error as a result: `Object(...) is not a function`.

Any idea?

[Edited]
When I console.log(contents) in PostDetail, the result is like this,
[image]

Seems like even in `contents`, the key 'content' already disappears...

Comment: How does `contents` look in `PostDetail`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Just added the image. It returns a pure array, which is also strange...

Comment: What is it that you find strange? Whatever you're passing to `RichText`, you're receiving it. Are you confused that your interface has a different structure and your component is receiving a different structure?

Comment: What I felt strange is that I thought I could received the array with key like this. `content: [...]`. Where did the key `content` go when passing props?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or use stack snippets to create it? I feel it would help to understand your problem more clearly.

Comment: I will temporarily work around the issue using `any` type. Thanks anyway! :)